# jquery dynamically print out value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a dynamic calculation program to practice jquery, but so far it's not going well, I can store the values in a variable, of course (see code here).

```
<form>
    Tafeltje van:
    <input type="number" name="tafel" id="tafel" />

    Aantal:
    <input type="number" name="aantal" id="aantal" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

and the JS:

```
var tafel = $('#tafel').val();
var aantal = $('#aantal').val();
```

How would one be able to print out these values in `output` while the user is typing in the text fields?

Comment: use `.keyup()` event and in keyup event add the values then out put it using `.text()` or `.html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your code with [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or `input` event of the inputs. Then, once you have got the values, you can use either [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to display the values in `#output` div in whatever format you want.

```
// $("input").on("keyup", function(){
$("input").on("input", function(){
  var tafel = $('#tafel').val();
  var aantal = $('#aantal').val();

  $("#output").text("tafel: " + tafel + " aantal: "+aantal);
});//keyup
```

Comment: `keydown` would make more sense, wouldn't it ? In case user keeps holding a key.

Comment: @you.know.nothing Yes, I checked around after your comment and I think native `input` event is more suited for it then. Let me know if `keydown` is better than `input`. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: That's even better :)

Comment: holy, totally forgot to set this as the answer, only just saw it as it popped up as getting 1k views, anyway, set as answer